# How can I limit the number of threads created by Tkinter button click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

im learning about threads and gui with tkinter and i have a question for you:

first of all here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from queue import Queue
import threading

num_threads = 8
enclosure_queue = Queue()


def deviceconnector(i, q):
    ip = q.get()
    print("Do something")

def main():
    for i in range(num_threads):

        thread = threading.Thread(target=deviceconnector, args=(i, enclosure_queue,), daemon=True)

        thread.start()
    print(threading.active_count())


root = tk.Tk()
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(side="right")
run_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Run HC", command=main)
run_button.grid(padx=10, pady=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

and the result is just a window with a button that will execute the main function that triggers threads to deviceconnector which i will use to connect to devices using netmiko, everything is working fine for after the function is called i print the thread.active_count() and i can see the count is increasing every time i click the button, also on my monitor i can see more and more ram being consumed.

So, is there a way to clean those threads and just to keep the initial 8?

[Here is a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1onxU.png)

what i expect is to keep the initial 8 threads after the button is clicked if that is possible

Comment: You could either disable the button after it's clicked, or make it so that if there are 8 threads, the code doesn't create any more of them. Either way, you can use an `if` statement along with the thread number to detect if you have the right number of threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example that uses the `threading` module and the `tkinter` library to create a simple GUI application.
The application performs device connections using multiple threads.

```
import threading
import datetime
import time
import tkinter as tk
from queue import Queue

num_devices = 10
num_threads = 3


def deviceconnector(ip):
    # Simulate device connection by sleeping for 2 seconds
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f"done {ip} at {datetime.datetime.now()}\n")


def _queued_methods(queue: Queue) -> None:
    """Do queued tasks"""
    while not queue.empty():
        method, params = queue.get()
        # Execute the method "deviceconnector" with the provided parameters "ip=10.0.0.1"
        method(**params)
        queue.task_done()


def main() -> None:
    # Create a queue to store tasks
    queue: Queue = Queue()
    for i in range(num_devices):
        # Add device connection tasks to the queue
        queue.put((deviceconnector, {"ip": f"10.0.0.{i}"}))

    for idx in range(num_threads):
        # Create threads that execute queued tasks
        thread = threading.Thread(target=_queued_methods, args=(queue,))
        # Start the thread
        thread.start()
    # Wait for all tasks in the queue to be completed
    queue.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    button_frame.pack(side="right")
    run_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Run HC", command=main)
    run_button.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```

output

```
done 10.0.0.2 at 2023-05-28 08:39:12.786582
done 10.0.0.0 at 2023-05-28 08:39:12.786582
done 10.0.0.1 at 2023-05-28 08:39:12.786582

done 10.0.0.4 at 2023-05-28 08:39:14.795944
done 10.0.0.3 at 2023-05-28 08:39:14.796357
done 10.0.0.5 at 2023-05-28 08:39:14.796427

done 10.0.0.8 at 2023-05-28 08:39:16.807337
done 10.0.0.7 at 2023-05-28 08:39:16.807337
done 10.0.0.6 at 2023-05-28 08:39:16.807337

done 10.0.0.9 at 2023-05-28 08:39:18.817837
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can check how many *active threads* are being executed, you can use that information to disable creating new threads as below:

```py
def main():
    threads = threading.active_count()
    print(f"{threads=}") # show current number of threads for debugging
    if threads <= 1:
        # there is at most one thread (the main thread) running
        # so create the required threads
        for i in range(num_threads):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=deviceconnector, args=(i, enclosure_queue,), daemon=True)
            thread.start()
        print(f"{num_threads} created")
```

Or using a global variable to store whether the threads are created or not:

```py
threads_created = False

def main():
    global threads_created
    if not threads_created:
        for i in range(num_threads):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=deviceconnector, args=(i, enclosure_queue,), daemon=True)
            thread.start()
        print(f"{num_threads} created, current number of threads is {threading.active_count()}")
        threads_created = True
    else:
        print("Threads already created")
```